# Close vote note indicated below the question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I just came across an old question with 18k views which asks for a plugin/library.

Both the answers for the question are link only. Hence I moved to the close section to find the following popup:

> [image: close view]

So it says I've already voted to close it, but the close vote is not indicated below the question as shown below.

> [image: question view]

Is it because I voted to close it once and then retracted it? (*I don't remember seeing this question before and I can't think of a reason for retracting the close vote if I did so*)

Or is it because the question was closed and re-opened? If so why is it reopened since it's asking for a plugin?

Comment: I positively love Robert Harvey's answer to that question. Yes, folks, back in 2009 even moderators had no trouble writing link-only answers.

Comment: note that one can check whether a question was closed / reopened by looking into its [revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/revisions-list): http://stackoverflow.com/posts/918873/revisions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close votes *expire*. You cast your close vote already, but it has now expired.

On questions with enough traffic (more than 100 views), close votes start to expire after 4 days, at a rate of one vote per day. If another close vote is cast within 4 days, expiration is halted again.

I found the [question you referred to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918873/drag-and-drop-between-multiple-lists-and-sortable); it is indeed a resource request and I have cast a close vote on it. Hopefully it'll get closed properly this time.

Comment: Why so..? so if i vote to close an old thread, am i just wasting my time? :/ anyway thanks for the info, here's the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918873/drag-and-drop-between-multiple-lists-and-sortable) do what is necessary.

Comment: If close votes didn't expire, popular, on-topic questions could get closed just because some lone voices in the wilderness cast close votes on it at a rate of once a year.

Comment: mmm… that's correct. way fast response ninja.!